# indexOf in an array not behaving correctly

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, loops

I'm attempting to use JS to check a string for the most amount of the letters and append that result to a div. It looks so far like this:

```js
var string = "AABBCCDDEEEEEEEEEE";
var stringInput = document.getElementById("string");

function showMostChar() {
 var newInput = string.split("");
  var inputAsArray = Array.of(newInput);
  for (i = 0; i > inputAsArray; i++) {
   if ((inputAsArray.indexOf("E")) > 9 ) {
     stringInput.innerHTML = "E"; 
    }
  }
}

window.onload = showMostChar;
```

```html
<div id="string"></div>
```

In plain english, I'm looking to split a string by character, which I then use to create an array. I loop through the array and if E has more than 9 (an arbitrary value) put E into the div. before I was using `array()` but I remembered thats not a valid function, [so I did research](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/of) and found `Array.of()` but I'm not seeing anything appended to string div.

1. is `Array.of()` not the right way to create an array in this context? If not why?
2. The ideal scenario is to log the total amount of characters that appear the most, so in this instance `EEEEEEEEEE`. I need to somehow get the value of each character and compare it to each other, somehow...something like:

   ```
   for (i = 0; i > inputAsArray; i++) {
    // somehow compare values to each other? e being each instance
    // so, would that be a loop within a loop?
   if ((i.value()) > e ) {
       stringInput.innerHTML = i;  
       }
     }
   ```

Comment: Have you tried `Array.from`?

Comment: A few things. First, is there a typo in your loop? `i > inputAsArray` seems odd since `inputAsArray` is not a number. Perhaps you meant `inputAsArray.length`. Second, by calling `Array.of` on the result of your split, your array is actually nested, eg if the string was `abc`, your `inputAsArray` is now `[["a", "b", "c"]]`.

Comment: `Array.of(whateverValue)` is the same as `[whateverValue]`

Comment: Is your goal to find the most frequent character in that string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are few things that needs to be fixed in your code:

- First of all `.split()` will return an `array` so `newInput` is
  already an `array`, you don't need any transform it.
- In the other hand the right method to create a new `array` is
  [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from), because [`Array.of()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/of) takes a `Number` as
  argument.
- Second thing you don't need any loop to check for the `.indexOf()`, you can directly call it upon `newInput` array.
- And it wasn't entering the if block because `.indexOf()` will return
  the first `index` of `E` in the array, which is lower than `9`, I
  used `5` for testing purpose here.

This is how should be your code:

```
function showMostChar() {
    var newInput = string.split("");
    if ((newInput.indexOf("E")) > 5 ) {
        stringInput.innerHTML = "E";    
    }
}
```

**Demo:**

```js
var string = "AABBCCDDEEEEEEEEEE";
var stringInput = document.getElementById("string");

function showMostChar() {
  var newInput = string.split("");
  console.log(newInput);
  if ((newInput.indexOf("E")) > 5) {
    stringInput.innerHTML = "E";
  }
}

window.onload = showMostChar;
```

```html
<div id="string"></div>
```

**Edit:**

To get the number of occurrences of `E` in the array, you can use `Array.filter()` like this:

```
function getNumberOfOccurences(char) {
    var newInput = string.split("");
  return newInput.filter(function(c){
      return c === char;
  }).length;
}
console.log(getNumberOfOccurences("E"));
```

**Demo:**

```js
var string = "AABBCCDDEEEEEEEEEE";
var stringInput = document.getElementById("string");

function getNumberOfOccurences(char) {
 var newInput = string.split("");
  return newInput.filter(function(c){
      return c === char;
  }).length;
}
console.log(getNumberOfOccurences("E"));
```

Comment: But theres 10 E's, howcome indexOf more than 9 didn't work? Because arrays start at 0? But if you're using `.length()` shouldn't that return 10...?

Comment: @kawnah `.indexOf()` returns the first index of the element and not its occurences number, take a look at my Edit, I implemented a function for this.